# How to update cell value to "" when other cell value changed?

Tags: excel, vba

I need if I change the value of cell K2, the value of cell E2 should be equal to "".

I need to do it for all rows, K3 E3, K4 E4, Kn En .. .

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target = Range("K2") Then
    Range("E2").Value = ""
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let try:

```
   Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)


   If Not(intersect(target,[K:k]) is nothing) Then Range("E" & target.row).Value = vbnullstring

   End Sub
```

Or better:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)


If target.column=[k:k].column and target.cells.count=1 Then Range("E" & target.row).Value = vbnullstring

End Sub
```

Comment: You could change that to `IF Target.column=11 And Target.Cells.count=1 Then Target.offset(,-6)=""`. Think that correct syntax. Bit drunk :)